# Blackberry-not getting soap response xml

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, mobile-application

I am trying to consume SOAP response xml by passing request xml in a string, using BlackBerry Java plugin for Eclipse.  I have been struck on this for the past two days looking for a way to solve it.

I have attached the sample code below.

```java
public String CheckXml()
{
     final String requestXml="<SOAP:Envelope xmlns:SOAP=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><header xmlns=\"http://schemas.cordys.com/General/1.0/\"></header><SOAP:Body><authenticateAgainstOID xmlns=\"http://schemas.cordys.com/OIDAuthentication\"><stringParam>HEMANTS_MUM013</stringParam><stringParam1>TATA2012</stringParam1></authenticateAgainstOID></SOAP:Body></SOAP:Envelope>";

     final String HOST_ADDRESS = "http://xyz.com/cordys/com.eibus.web.soap.Gateway.wcp?organization=o=B2C,cn=cordys,cn=cbop,o=tatamotors.com&SAMLart=MDFn+8e5dRDaRMRIwMY7nI84eEccbx+lIiV0VhsOQ7u+SKG6n5+WNB58"; 
     String result="";
     try {
         HttpConnection url=(HttpConnection)Connector.open(HOST_ADDRESS);
         url.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml");
         url.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.GET);
         OutputStreamWriter writer=new OutputStreamWriter(url.openOutputStream());

         writer.write(requestXml);
         writer.flush();
         writer.close();
         StringBuffer buffer1=new StringBuffer();

         InputStreamReader reader=new InputStreamReader(url.openInputStream());
         StringBuffer buffer=new StringBuffer();
         char[] cbuf=new char[2048];
         int num;

         while (-1 != (num = reader.read(cbuf))) {
            buffer.append(cbuf, 0, num);
         }

         String result1 = buffer.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the main issue that you aren't asking `http. getResponseCode()`. I think BB doesn't do any interaction until you call it.

I would also be careful with this code on the real devices. Search for correct opening connection on the BlackBerries.

Comment: i have tried that also for checking the http connection, i have posted the code here, if(url.getResponseCode()==HttpConnection.HTTP_OK)
       {
        InputStream inputStream=url.openInputStream();
        buffer.append(IOUtilities.streamToBytes(inputStream));
         result=buffer.toString();
        
       } but its not working for me

Comment: What did you get? Some exception? Maybe you need to set some accept headers. Could you sniff desktop client and check headers that it sends to server/ Maybe you need to change method from GET to POST.

Comment: Hi after changing and checked all the way still now am getting the same error like class not found near inputstreamreader line.

Comment: I think that InputStreamReader is available from 5.0 OS. What device/sim do you use for testing?

Comment: Hi am using 4.2.06 simulator.just now checked, will try in 5.0 right away.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you are not including the SoapAction header in the request.

SOAP Web services usually have a fixed URL, and the differents methods are selected with the SoapAction header. You can check the header by opening the WSDL in a browser and inspecting the format for the method you want to invoke.

Once you know which action to select, set it as a regular http header:

```
url.setRequestProperty("SOAPAction", <your action here>);
```

Another source of problems in your code is that you are using the old `HttpConnection` class that requires appending a suffix to the URL depending on the transport type (MDS, BIS, Wi-Fi, etc). You don't need to use this legacy class unless you are targeting OS 4.5 and lower. So have a look at `ConnectionFactory` class, which is much easier to use. It is available since OS 5.0.

Comment: Hi i have tried all the factors, and am not even getting positive result to keep next step. and also this is not a wsdl service format.passing request xml, reponse xml should come in a string format

Comment: In what line does it fail? What type of Exception is thrown?

Comment: through break point am checking, it falls in inputstreamreader after it throws source not found.wat simulator to use for 5 OS version.

Comment: Source code not found is usually shown when you try to step into a RIM class when debugging, or an exception is thrown and the debugger wants to position in the failing line inside a RIM class. Just push the continue button in debugger, and let the app log the error. BTW, `InputStreamReader` is available in OS 4.2 also, no need to switch to OS 5.0.